# How may I integrate Pyarrow with Pytorch Dataset when dataset is too large to load into memory at once?

Tags: pytorch, pyarrow, pytorch-dataloader

A typical Pytorch Dataset implementation can be as follows:

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data[:][:-1]
        self.target = data[:][-1]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x = self.data[index]
        y = self.target[index]

        return x, y
```

The reason I want to implement it in `Dataset` is because I want to use pytorch `DataLoader` later for my mini-batch training.

However, if `data` is from a directory containing multiple parquet files, how can I write `def __getitem__(self, index):` for it with loading all data into memory? I know `Pyarrow` is good at loading data in bathes but I didn't find a good reference to make it work. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!